# Toilet behaviour

Tags: dogs

My male mastiff is 8 months old & has just finished puppy pad training. However since he started to cock his leg to pee, he has started to pee up a chair in the house. How do I get him to stop?

Comment: What have you tried when it comes to discouraging him? Do you clean the spot he marks thoroughly? Does he pee often on a walk? How many walks a day?... A lot of the above answers will help.

Comment: This is the problem with puppy pads -- they give the dog permission to eliminate in the house. You need to properly housetrain him. I would start from the beginning with a crate.

Answer (score 2):

Experience has taught me that it's not a matter of making him 'stop' to pee inside, up a chair in this case, but to offer your dog plenty of peeing opportunities outside.

Take him outside, and patiently wait until he pees. In the very beginning this may take 30 minutes, even an hour, but it becomes easier and faster the more you train this.

Once your mastiff pees, say 'pee pee' and reward him with treats. Rinse and repeat every hour (if your dog still has the urge to pee inside, repeat faster), and after a while your dog will know that he'll be rewarded when/if he pees outside.

Comment: Good answer. Just to add a male dog won't fully empty their bladder on the first pee either (if they pee for a good 30-45 seconds your probably ok though) give him the opportunity to mark a few places when out walking as well.